# Creating a html table by looping through 2d arrays in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, loops, ruby-on-rails-4, html-table

I'm trying to get these arrays:

```
table_header  = ["val1", "val2", "val2"]
name_column   = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
val1_column   = ["12", "12", "12"]
val2_column   = ["123", "123", "123"]
val3_column   = ["1234", "1234", "1234"]
```

into a table like this

```
| Name   |  val1  |  val2 | val3 |
----------------------------------
| name1  |  12    |  123  | 1234 |
----------------------------------
| name2  |  12    |  123  | 1234 |
----------------------------------
| name3  |  12    |  123  | 1234 |
----------------------------------
```

Here is what i have which gives me the table header and name column

```
<table id="example" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>

    <%  table_header.each do |header| %>
      <th> <%= header %> </th>
    <%  end %>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
       <%  name_column.each do |name| %>
        <tr>
         <td> <%= name  %> </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

My problem now is that I cant loop the value columns into the table. I've tried a few things but none of them are working.

I can have all the rows in arrays like below but there could be hundreds of rows plus the name_column values cant be added to the arrays below so its better to have them stored in column arrays.

```
first_row_vals  = ["12", "123", "1234"] 
second_row_vals = ["12", "123", "1234"] 
third_row_vals  = ["12", "123", "1234"]
```

If you think it will be easier with row arrays like the ones above i'm happy to give it a go.

I'm sure there is some simple way of doing this but it wont pop into my head.

Comment: It's not exactly the 2d arrays you know, are you ok with changing the structure to something like `table = [[value1, value2, value3], [value4, value5, value6], [value7, value8, value9]]`?

Comment: Yea i can put the arrays in an array if it makes it easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use the row_vals structure, I would suggest this way:

```
<tbody>
  <% [first_row_vals, second_row_vals, third_row_vals].each_with_index do |row, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= name_column[index] %> </td>
      <% row.each do |value| %>
        <td> <%= value %> </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

For larger set of rows, you could go with a 2d array as I proposed in your question's comments.

```
rows_vals = []
rows_vals << ["1", "2", "3", "..."] 
rows_vals << ["4", "5", "6", "..."] 
# ...
# row_vals = [["1", "2", "3", "..."], ["4", "5", "6", "..."], ...]
```

Then the work should be even easier

```
<tbody>
  <% rows_vals.each_with_index do |row, index| %>
    <tr>
      <td> <%= name_column[index] %> </td>
      <% row.each do |value| %>
        <td> <%= value %> </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works if there is a set amount of rows or a small number of rows but there will be 50-150+ rows, I can put the values arrays into an array like you suggested in your comment. can you update the answer for that method?

Comment: I guess the arrays might not need to be stored in variables. `g.rows[0].data, g.rows[1].data, g.rows[2].data` etc.. is what i use to store the row array in a variable, so it might be easier to just store all them in an array instead of putting all them into variables then putting all the variables into an array?

Comment: Then you could go with 2d array, I have edited the answer accordingly, have fun bro!